# Retrieving currently playing song from Windows Media Player (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I realize there is a similar question to this, but it really has no information in it. I want to retrieve the currently playing song title (similar to MSN Messenger) within a C# app. The Windows Media Player I want to control is EXTERNAL- that is, it is running on the computer, not within the app. Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found a way around my problem- a simple solution is to install a plugin that tells you the current playing song and writes it to a file and you can read it through your program.

Comment: Could you provide a link to that plugin?

Comment: Here I found it myself:
http://brandon.fuller.name/archives/hacks/nowplaying/wmp/